# CSS - fill right column remaining width when left column has width as % and max-width as px

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns. The first is 30% width, and second is 70% width.
However, when the screen is wide enough, col-0 width is limited to 300px. How can I make col-1 width expand to fit the rest of the page width?

```css
#col-0{
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 2em;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}
#col-1{
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="col-0"></div>
<div id="col-1"></div>
```

Comment: You can use flex

Comment: Use `calc()` inside an appropriate media query, to calculate 100% - 300px.

Comment: CBroe this worked, thanks.

Comment: No need for `calc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this for the CSS of `#col-1`

```css
#col-0{
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 2em;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}
#col-1{
    min-width: 70%;
    min-height: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    width:calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

```html
<div id="col-0"></div>
<div id="col-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). Something like this:

```css
.column-container {
  display: flex;
}

#col-0 {
  flex: 0 1 30%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 2em;
  background: red;
}

#col-1 {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
  min-height: 2em;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-container">
  <div id="col-0"></div>
  <div id="col-1"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1s0ncuwc/)

P.S CSS Tricks has a very helpful [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to flexbox.

Also, a small comment on your original CSS - when using a `float`, a `display` property will have no effect.